# How to find the root element of a TreeSet

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a tree set. How to find the root element of the treeset:

```
TreeSet<Integer> ts = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    ts.add(8);
    ts.add(3);
    ts.add(8);
    ts.add(1);
    ts.add(0);
    ts.add(4);
    ts.add(7);
```

If we are taking the below treeset, 20 is the root element:
[image: TreeSet]

Comment: What do you mean the root element?

Comment: @user I have updated the question. Could you please have a look

Comment: Why do you care? The root node will change as nodes are added and the tree is rebalanced.  Which node is the "root" is transitory and an insignificant implementation detail.  If you want to peek under the covers, take a look at the Java source code on GrepCode, but I doubt you'll find anything that will give you access to the internal state.

Comment: You probably think the root element has some special property that it does not have.  It is not the median element, for example.

Comment: @Jim he is asking about root element once TreeMap contains all inserted element.

Comment: @LovaChittumuri  My question still stands. The "root" element has no special significance and is an implementation detail.

Comment: Yes @lova i am thinking of getting the root element of the tree once all the elements are inserted.

Comment: @Jim yes... It has no significance when comparing with other elements. Just wondering is there a way of finding the root.

Comment: Yes @JitheshGopinathan one the tree element is inserted we can find the root element. but while keep inserting elements the root element keep changing as per the theory of Red-Black Tree and Balanced Tree Concept. There is no exact API method is not there to find the root element.

Comment: If there was it might be different each time you run the code, depending on the exact order in which nodes were added to the tree.  Any code that needs to be aware of and depend on an implementation detail such as this will be fragile and prone to failure.  Take another example: A `HashMap` contains an array of buckets and objects are distributed based on their hash code.  It is not meaningful to ask which objects hashed to a particular bucket as that can change from one execution to the next.  That question has the same significance as asking which object is the "root" in a tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you absolute need (desire?) to know what the current root value is, you can use reflection.

*Beware:* Internal implementation of `TreeSet` and `TreeMap` may change and the following code will fail. The code has been tested with JDK 1.8u91.
Also, the code will fail with a `SecurityException` if a security manager is present.

The following two helper methods can be used to give you the root of a `TreeSet` and a `TreeMap`.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <E> E getTreeRoot(TreeSet<E> ts) {
    try {
        Field mField = TreeSet.class.getDeclaredField("m");
        mField.setAccessible(true);
        return getTreeRoot((TreeMap<E, Object>) mField.get(ts));
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Internals of TreeSet has changed", e);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <K,V> K getTreeRoot(TreeMap<K,V> tm) {
    try {
        Field rootField = TreeMap.class.getDeclaredField("root");
        rootField.setAccessible(true);
        Map.Entry<K,V> root = (Map.Entry<K,V>) rootField.get(tm);
        return (root == null ? null : root.getKey());
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Internals of TreeMap has changed", e);
    }
}
```

**Test Helper**

```
private static void test(int... values) {
    TreeSet<Integer> ts = new TreeSet<>();
    System.out.println("Root is " + getTreeRoot(ts) + " for " + ts);
    for (int v : values) {
        ts.add(v);
        System.out.println("Root is " + getTreeRoot(ts) + " for " + ts);
    }
}
```

**Test 1** (values in question)

```
test(8, 3, 8, 1, 0, 4, 7);
```

```
Root is null for []
Root is 8 for [8]
Root is 8 for [3, 8]
Root is 8 for [3, 8]
Root is 3 for [1, 3, 8]
Root is 3 for [0, 1, 3, 8]
Root is 3 for [0, 1, 3, 4, 8]
Root is 3 for [0, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8]
```

**Test 2** (values in graph in *ascending* order)

```
test(5, 15, 17, 18, 20, 22, 25, 27, 30);
```

```
Root is null for []
Root is 5 for [5]
Root is 5 for [5, 15]
Root is 15 for [5, 15, 17]
Root is 15 for [5, 15, 17, 18]
Root is 15 for [5, 15, 17, 18, 20]
Root is 15 for [5, 15, 17, 18, 20, 22]
Root is 15 for [5, 15, 17, 18, 20, 22, 25]
Root is 18 for [5, 15, 17, 18, 20, 22, 25, 27]
Root is 18 for [5, 15, 17, 18, 20, 22, 25, 27, 30]
```

**Test 3** (values in graph in *descending* order)

```
test(30, 27, 25, 22, 20, 18, 17, 15, 5);
```

```
Root is null for []
Root is 30 for [30]
Root is 30 for [27, 30]
Root is 27 for [25, 27, 30]
Root is 27 for [22, 25, 27, 30]
Root is 27 for [20, 22, 25, 27, 30]
Root is 27 for [18, 20, 22, 25, 27, 30]
Root is 27 for [17, 18, 20, 22, 25, 27, 30]
Root is 22 for [15, 17, 18, 20, 22, 25, 27, 30]
Root is 22 for [5, 15, 17, 18, 20, 22, 25, 27, 30]
```

As you can see, the root depends on the order of insertion.